# The scanf 'maximum field width' includes whitespace?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

Suppose we have

```
int n;
sscanf(" 42", "%2d", &n);
```

Should `n` be 4 (the whitespace accounted for by the "%2d") or 42 (whitespace ignored, making scanf read 3 characters)?

*[ideone implementation](https://ideone.com/C1ZfzB) reads 3 characters*

Comment: From the man page on MacOS: *"Before conversion begins, most conversions skip white space;
     this white space is not counted against the field width."*

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX specification for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html)
is fairly clear about the processing:

> The format is a character string, … composed of zero or more directives. Each directive is composed of one of the following: one or more white-space characters (`<space>`, `<tab>`, `<newline>`, `<vertical-tab>`, or `<form-feed>`); an ordinary character (neither '`%`' nor a white-space character); or a conversion specification. Each conversion specification is introduced by the character '`%`' [CX] ⌦ or the character sequence "%n$", ⌫ after which the following appear in sequence:
>
> …
>
> A directive that is a conversion specification defines a set of matching input sequences, as described below for each conversion character. A conversion specification shall be executed in the following steps.
>
> Input white-space characters (as specified by `isspace`) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifier.
>
> An item shall be read from the input, unless the conversion specification includes an `n` conversion specifier. An input item shall be defined as the longest sequence of input bytes (up to any specified maximum field width, which may be measured in characters or bytes dependent on the conversion specifier) which is an initial subsequence of a matching sequence. The first byte, if any, after the input item shall remain unread. If the length of the input item is 0, the execution of the conversion specification shall fail; this condition is a matching failure, unless end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which case it is an input failure.

If white space is skipped by a conversion specification (`%…`), it is not counted as part of the field width; the skipping occurs before any counting does.

The equivalent specification in C11 [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) is very similar (but it doesn't include the 'C extension' markup, of course).

Answer (score 3):

> The scanf 'maximum field width' includes whitespace?

Yes for `[` and `c`.
No for other specifiers.
`"%n"` does not apply.

The `fscanf()`  (C11dr §7.21.6.2 7-9)

> 7 ... A conversion specification is executed in the **following steps:**
>
> 8 Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are **skipped**, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.
>
> 9 An input item is read from the stream, ... An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field **width** and ....

The *width* applies after leading input white-space character consumption.

---

Further, as I read the spec, if the conversion fails, the input white-space characters remained consumed.

Comment: The last sentence added a new bit of learning. Will have to test if that is consistently implemented by the various compilers. Will drop a note if any are outliers there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Look forward to your findings.

Comment: Of course the whitespace remains consumed - because it is done with `ungetc` that has only one character guaranteed putback. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Wow, new revelation when reading the documentation for `ungetc` - the argument `ungetc` must be *unsigned char*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `fscanf()` push back as if with `ungetc()` and `ungetc()` has "One character of pushback is guaranteed. If the ungetc function is called too many
times on the same stream without an intervening read or file positioning operation on that stream, the operation may fail."  IMO, weasel words that allow pushing back more than one, _sometimes_. IOWs, implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @chux my point is that the required specification doesn't go beyond what you can achieve with one character pushback.

Comment: @chux - gcc/clang/VS10 (on SuSE, Arch and Win7) all show the correct behavior (I can't believe one of them didn't bork it `:)` [fscanf whitespace check](http://susepaste.org/view//80047182) - verification code used (link expires: Mon May  6 22:55:32 CDT 2019)

Answer (score 1):

From the BSD manual page:

> In addition to these flags, there may be an optional maximum field width,
>        expressed as a decimal integer, between the % and the conversion.  If no width is
>        given, a default of ``infinity'' is used (with one exception, below); otherwise
>        at most this many bytes are scanned in processing the conversion.  In the case of
>        the lc, ls and l[ conversions, the field width specifies the maximum number of
>        multibyte characters that will be scanned.  Before conversion begins, most conversions skip white space; this white space is not counted against the field
>        width.

The Linux man page has

> An  optional  decimal integer which specifies the maximum field width.  Reading
>                 of characters stops either when this maximum is reached or when  a  nonmatching
>                 character  is found, whichever happens first.  Most conversions discard initial
>                 white space characters (the exceptions are noted below),  and  these  discarded
>                 characters  don't  count  toward the maximum field width.  String input conversions store a terminating null byte ('\0') to mark the end of  the  input;  the
>                 maximum field width does not include this terminator.

both specify that the whitespace does not count against the field width.